# Need Help Looping Out Content Of Json Data Response Fetched From DB In Using Ajax And Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a table with a list of subjects, each subject has its own topics, so I wrote an ajax script to fetch the topics of each subject "onclick" of the subject, using the subject id.

I tried console logging the JSON success response from my controller, I'm seeing the results of the query so I used Js append functionality to append the data to a div on my index.blade but its returning topics:[object Object],[object Object]

Ajax Request To Show Topics of Selected Subjects track_id means subject_id

````
$( ".show-topics" ).click(function() {
    var track_id= $(this).data('id');
    var html ='';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'showTopics',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
        data: {'id': track_id},
        success: function(data)
        {
            // For loop statement to loop out the data```
            if(data.topics)
            {
                for(var key in data)
                {   
                    var value = data[key];
                    html+='<div>'+key+':'+value+'</div>'
                }
                $("#topic-data").append(html);
            }
        }
    });
});
````

In my controller, I have this as my showtopics method ```

```
public function showTopics(Request $request)
{ 
    $topics = Topic::where('track_id', $request->id)->latest()->get();
    return response()->json(['topics' => $topics]);
}
```

the div to append those data:

```
<div id="topic-data">
</div>
```

When I 
`console.log(data.topics)`
I got this,
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
created_at: "2019-07-29 18:04:32"
duration: 5
id: 7
title: "My Porfolio Adesanya Folorunso"
track_id: 44
updated_at: "2019-07-29 18:04:32"

1:
created_at: "2019-07-29 18:04:11"
duration: 2
id: 6
title: "Adesanya Folorunso"
track_id: 44
updated_at: "2019

I want to display topics->id, topics->title and duration.
not this topics:[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: What does your json look like? Please edit your question to show this.

Comment: You probably want to loop through `data.topics` not `data`

Comment: Hi @lee-taylor This is what i have for json ` return response()->json(['topics' => $topics]);`

Comment: No, please edit your question and add a sample of what your json looks like. Not the code that generates the json...

Comment: I've done that. Check again please

Comment: Please see my second comment above ^^^

Comment: Yes, I just edited my question, i added this (2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
created_at: "2019-07-29 18:04:32"
duration: 5
id: 7
title: "My Porfolio Adesanya Folorunso"
track_id: 44
updated_at: "2019-07-29 18:04:32"
__proto__: Object
1:
created_at: "2019-07-29 18:04:11"
duration: 2
id: 6
title: "Adesanya Folorunso"
track_id: 44
updated_at: "2019

Comment: OK. What happens when you loop through `data.topics` instead of `data`?

Comment: I have this 0:[object Object]
1:[object Object] , using this code `  if(data.topics)
                        {
                            for(var key in data.topics)
                            {
                                var value = data.topics[key];
                                html+='<div>'+key+':'+value+'</div>'
                            }
                            $("#topic-data").append(html);
                        }`

Comment: Please see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your data looks something like the following. If so, replace your loop code with mine...

```js
var data = 
{
    "topics":
    [
        {
            "created_at":"2019-07-29 18:04:32",
            "duration":5,
            "id":7,
            "title":"My Porfolio Adesanya Folorunso",
            "track_id":44,
            "updated_at":"2019-07-29 18:04:32"
        },
        {
            "created_at":"2019-07-29 18:04:11",
            "duration":2,
            "id":6,
            "title":"Adesanya Folorunso",
            "track_id":44,
            "updated_at":"2019-07-30 19:04:21"
        }
    ]
};

if(data.topics)
{
  for(var i=0; i < data.topics.length; i++)
  {
    $("#topic-data").append( $("<div />").text(data.topics[i].created_at) );
    $("#topic-data").append( $("<div />").text(data.topics[i].duration) );
    $("#topic-data").append( $("<hr />") );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topic-data">
</div>
```

Comment: I've seen it, I will try it now, and get back to you with as soon as possible

Comment: Yea, your code works fine,  So I had one issue, the output is being duplicated per click, I was able to fix that with `$(#topic-data").empty();` .Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @folorunso Glad I could help!